# How to change pie chart colours in a custom TFS widget

Tags: javascript, tfs, widget

I've to change default bar color in a custom `tfs widget`, how can I do this?
I know there a `"color"` option but I can't find the correct syntax.
Thanks.

Here's my chart code:

```
             chartOptions = {
                "hostOptions": {
                    "height": "290",
                    "width": "300"
                },
                "chartType": "bar",
                "series": [{
                    "data": [myBugs, myVuln, myCodeSm]
                }],
                "xAxis": {
                    "labelValues": ["Bugs", "Vulnerabilities", "Code smells"]
                },
                "specializedOptions": {
                    "showLabels": "true",
                    "size": 200
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your custom colors like below:

```
chartOptions = {
  "hostOptions": {
    "height": "290",
    "width": "300"
  },
  "colorCustomizationOptions": {
    "customColors": ["#FF0000", "#00CC00", "#302772"]
  },
  "chartType": "bar",
  "series": [{
    "data": [myBugs, myVuln, myCodeSm]
  }],
  "xAxis": {
    "labelValues": ["Bugs", "Vulnerabilities", "Code smells"]
  },
  "specializedOptions": {
    "showLabels": "true",
    "size": 200
  }
};
```

Comment: @SaimonCavallari try add color values in double quotes like “red”, “blue”, “green”

Comment: @SaimonCavallari one more thing I noticed. In question title you mentioned that its a **pie** chart but in your code it is showing **bar**. Can you confirm it.

Comment: I try like this but it doesn't work: "color": ["#FF0000", "#00CC00", "#302772"]. Pie chart and bar chart parameters are the same.

Comment: @SaimonCavallari can you please make a working snippet of your code. That would be faster to debug and find the solution. You can use jsfiddle or plunker or SO’s snippet tool.

Comment: I've copied entire code from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-chart?view=vsts you can use this code for test the color property

Comment: @SaimonCavallari please check answer now. I have updated

Comment: yes I try it but it gave me a strange error (an error related to a configuration tab that is in another file). If I remove:  "colorCustomizationOptions": {
    "customColors": ["#FF0000", "#00CC00", "#302772"]
  }, Error vanish....

Comment: Error is "Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined" but is not referred to another file, I don't know....

Answer (score 0):

In vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/charts.d.ts I found that customColors is a ColorEntry array. ColorEntry has two string properties: value, backgroundColor. With some trial and error I found out that value should be the label for which you want to set the color.

So I think this should work:

```
chartOptions = {
            "hostOptions": {
                "height": "290",
                "width": "300"
            },
            "chartType": "bar",
            "series": [{
                "data": [myBugs, myVuln, myCodeSm]
            }],
            "xAxis": {
                "labelValues": ["Bugs", "Vulnerabilities", "Code smells"]
            },
            "colorCustomizationOptions": {
                "customColors": [
                    {backgroundColor: "#FF0000", value: "Bugs"},
                    {backgroundColor: "#00CC00", value: "Vulnerabilities"},
                    {backgroundColor: "#302772", value: "Code smells"}
                ]
            },
            "specializedOptions": {
                "showLabels": "true",
                "size": 200
            }
        };
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.